# Third normal form with foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a car agency database for university project in third normal from and I have some doubts about the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Branches 
(
    Branch_Id PRIMARY KEY,
    City,
    Street,
    Manager
)

CREATE TABLE Customers 
(
    C_Id PRIMARY KEY,
    C_Name,
    Gender,
    City,
    City,
    Street,
    Email,
    Branch_Id FOREIGN KEY
)

CREATE TABLE Cars 
(
    Car_Id PRIMARY KEY,
    Car_model,
    C_color,
    C_fuel_type,
    Branch_Id FOREIGN KEY
)
```

As you can see from the columns above the cars and the customers have a `Branch_ID` as a foreign key.

Does it support 3NF? Or do I need to exclude the `branch_id` from these two tables?

Comment: What if a single Customer visits multiple Branches? What if a car is picked-up at one branch and dropped-off at another?

Comment: In real-life, a modern database would not have a "Gender" field for Customers as it's an unnecessarily personal detail that's irrelevant to the business (storing a person's salutation is acceptable, however). Consult a GDPR expert for more information about the design of databases that store PII.

Comment: @Dai i understand but what about the 3nf is it ok?

Comment: I believe the design *as-is* is 3NF. However, this design has data-modelling problems which I mentioned above.

Comment: I think it’s best to always jump to 5NF rather than targeting 1NF through 4NF. That said, this model so-far isn’t elaborate enough so 5NF will look the same as 3NF. I think undergraduate database classes should just only teach 5NF and beyond (and cover immutability and event-sourcing) - I think homework on 1NF/2NF/3NF/4NF is counterproductive.

Comment: I believe it is 3NF but the table fields are not appropriate e.g. Car ID, would be a [VIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number); Customers table would have a driving licence or some other gov issued identifier recorded etc.